# Steganography, convert/hide data to image

Tags: javascript, binary, hide, steganography

I have been studying **steganography** in the past few weeks. I understand that it is possible to conceal data inside of an image using the RGB pixel values, but I don't know how to do it.

I want to know how I convert/hide any binary data within an image. I am not worried about the image appearance or content, it can even be blank or nonsensical.

> I am aware that another method of hiding data is to concatenate the image and the binary data, but I do not want to do that. I want to actual conceal binary data inside of the image.

My preferred programming language is Javascript, but I have no experience with modifing images' binary data.

Can you please tell me if it is possible, and if it is, how to achieve it in Javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: You're asking more than one questions, which are also unclear. You say what you want to do, but not what is preventing you from doing it. If you're also interested in any language in particular, you should add the relevant tags.

Comment: Sorry about that. As I clearly not know if it is possible and if yes then how to do it. I will add the tag. I have modify the question to make it clear also I added the javascript tag.

Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible possible to hide raw data within pictures using different methods. For instance, doing bitwise operations on the less significant bit of each pixel byte so that the byte represents a character on the ascii code. This will not affect the appearance of the picture, at least not for the human eye.

Depending on the size of picture itself, you might hide more or less data. Usually, people who do steganography hide a short message and not a file.

In order to get the hidden message you need to reverse the process. Hence, you need to open the picture containing the hidden message as a file-like object in binary mode and read through each one of its pixel bytes, and finally see what ascii char each byte matches.

If you really desire to hide files you might consider using a set of pictures, instead of just one.

I do not know how one would do that in JavaScript, but in Python this is one way to do [it](https://hackernoon.com/simple-image-steganography-in-python-18c7b534854f)